# Xquery in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I am trying to parse my XML elements for the XML shown here. I need different elements from hierarchy.

I needs some attributes of all repeated elements of `E1EDKA1` and `E1EDK02`.

If I set my XPath to

```
@XML.nodes('//*:ZINVOIC2/*:IDOC/*:E1EDKA1')
```

I am able to access elements of `E1EDKA1` and `E1EDK01`. But I have multiple elements of `E1EDK02.QUALF`. How can I get all records of `E1EDK02.QUALF`  in separate rows?

Code for this is

```
SELECT 
t.c.query('E1EDK01/BELNR').value('.','char(15)') as INV_NO,
 t.c.query('E1EDKA1/PARVW').value('.','char(10)') as CUST_NO,
 t.c.query('E1EDKA1/NAME1').value('.','char(50)') as CUST_NAME,
 t.c.query('E1EDK02/QUALF').value('.','char(50)') as QUALF
FROM @XML.nodes('//*:ZINVOIC2/*:IDOC') t(c);
```

How should I fix this. I have multiple such attributes and don't want to create different queries for each and then join back the result.

```
 <ZINVOIC2>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
      <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      <MANDT>100</MANDT>
      <DOCNUM>0000022222017973</DOCNUM>
       </EDI_DC40>
    <!--header general data information-->
    <E1EDK01 SEGMENT="1">
      <CURCY>GBP</CURCY>
      <HWAER>GBP</HWAER>
      <BELNR>9650019904</BELNR>
      <FKTYP>L</FKTYP>
      <Z1EDK01 SEGMENT="1">
        <TAXID>37-1652702</TAXID>
      </Z1EDK01>
      <Z1INCO SEGMENT="1">
        <INCO1>EXW</INCO1>
        <INCO1_TXT>Ex Works</INCO1_TXT>
      </Z1INCO>
      <ZINVREF SEGMENT="1">
        <ZNETDT>20220125</ZNETDT>
        <ZDSDT1>20220125</ZDSDT1>
        <DISCOUNTDUE>12427.39</DISCOUNTDUE>
        <SFAKN>N</SFAKN>
        <KALSM>YIS001</KALSM>
        <ZCONTACT_NUM>01542 832327</ZCONTACT_NUM>
        <FKART>YRIN</FKART>
        <KNUMV>0008498319</KNUMV>
        <VBTYP>M</VBTYP>
        <BEZEI>Ex Works</BEZEI>
        <KSCHL>ZMP6</KSCHL>
      </ZINVREF>
    </E1EDK01>
    <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
      <PARVW>RS</PARVW>
      <LIFNR>1111164896</LIFNR>
      <NAME1>XYZ Company</NAME1>
      <NAME2>XYZ Company Limited</NAME2>
      <STRAS>Sugarland str</STRAS>
      <ORT01>LONDON</ORT01>
      <PSTLZ>EC1A 4HD</PSTLZ>
      <LAND1>GB</LAND1>
      <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
      <BNAME>PRODERP</BNAME>
      <PAORG>MK40</PAORG>
    </E1EDKA1>
    <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
      <PARVW>AG</PARVW>
      <PARTN>1111164896</PARTN>
      <NAME1>OILS LTD</NAME1>
      <STRAS>MARINE PLACE</STRAS>
      <ORT01>BUCKIE</ORT01>
      <PSTLZ>AB56 1UT</PSTLZ>
      <LAND1>GB</LAND1>
      <TELF1>01542 832327</TELF1>
      <TELFX>01542 833319</TELFX>
      <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
      <REGIO>MR</REGIO>
      <SPRAS_ISO>EN</SPRAS_ISO>
    </E1EDKA1>
    <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
      <PARVW>RE</PARVW>
      <PARTN>1111164896</PARTN>
      <NAME1>OILS LTD</NAME1>
      <STRAS>MARINE PLACE</STRAS>
      <ORT01>BUCKIE</ORT01>
      <PSTLZ>AB56 1UT</PSTLZ>
      <LAND1>GB</LAND1>
      <TELF1>01542 832327</TELF1>
      <TELFX>01542 833319</TELFX>
      <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
      <REGIO>MR</REGIO>
      <SPRAS_ISO>EN</SPRAS_ISO>
    </E1EDKA1>
    <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
      <PARVW>RG</PARVW>
      <PARTN>1111164896</PARTN>
      <NAME1>OILS LTD</NAME1>
      <STRAS>MARINE PLACE</STRAS>
      <ORT01>BUCKIE</ORT01>
      <PSTLZ>AB56 1UT</PSTLZ>
      <LAND1>GB</LAND1>
      <TELF1>01542 832327</TELF1>
      <TELFX>01542 833319</TELFX>
      <SPRAS>E</SPRAS>
      <REGIO>MR</REGIO>
      <SPRAS_ISO>EN</SPRAS_ISO>
    </E1EDKA1>
    <E1EDKA1 SEGMENT="1">
      <PARVW>BK</PARVW>
      <LIFNR>1040</LIFNR>
      <NAME1>XYZ Mktg Br</NAME1>
      <NAME2>ABC Ltd</NAME2>
      <STRAS>Sugarstreet</STRAS>
      <ORT01>LONDON</ORT01>
      <PSTLZ>EC1A 4HD</PSTLZ>
      <LAND1>GB</LAND1>
    </E1EDKA1>
    <!--header reference data-->
    <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
      <QUALF>009</QUALF>
      <BELNR>9659999904</BELNR>
      <DATUM>20220101</DATUM>
    </E1EDK02>
    <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
      <QUALF>002</QUALF>
      <BELNR>0201555555</BELNR>
      <DATUM>20220120</DATUM>
    </E1EDK02>
    <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
      <QUALF>012</QUALF>
      <BELNR>0082222514</BELNR>
      <DATUM>20210423</DATUM>
    </E1EDK02>
    <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
      <QUALF>017</QUALF>
      <BELNR>9650019904</BELNR>
    </E1EDK02>
    <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
      <QUALF>087</QUALF>
      <BELNR>9650019904</BELNR>
    </E1EDK02>`enter code here`
    <!--date segment-->
    <E1EDK03 SEGMENT="1">
      <IDDAT>026</IDDAT>
      <DATUM>20220120</DATUM>
    </E1EDK03>
    <E1EDK03 SEGMENT="1">
      <IDDAT>001</IDDAT>
      <DATUM>20210423</DATUM>
    </E1EDK03>
    <E1EDK03 SEGMENT="1">
      <IDDAT>012</IDDAT>
      <DATUM>20220120</DATUM>
    </E1EDK03>
    <E1EDK03 SEGMENT="1">
      <IDDAT>011</IDDAT>
      <DATUM>20220120</DATUM>
    </E1EDK03>
    <E1EDK03 SEGMENT="1">
      <IDDAT>024</IDDAT>
      <DATUM>20220101</DATUM>
    </E1EDK03>
    <E1EDK03 SEGMENT="1">
      <IDDAT>028</IDDAT>
      <DATUM>20220115</DATUM>
    </E1EDK03>
    <E1EDK03 SEGMENT="1">
      <IDDAT>048</IDDAT>
      <DATUM>20220101</DATUM>
    </E1EDK03>
    <!--taxes-->
    <E1EDK04 SEGMENT="1">
      <MWSKZ>G1</MWSKZ>
      <MSATZ>20.000</MSATZ>
      <MWSBT>1394.86</MWSBT>
    </E1EDK04>
  </IDOC>
</ZINVOIC2>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your query (and preferably input XML and desired output) as text, not images or fragments. As written it's virtually impossible for anyone to help out unless they first imagine what your input looks like and then manually re-type everything, which few people will be willing to do. If your input is too large, at least condense it to a [mre].

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Bad habits to kick: using wildcard namespaces in Xquery, e.g.: `*:ZINVOIC2`, is not very performant and likely to yield unexpected results at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `E1EDK02/QUALF` values determine the nature of the `E1EDK02` contents, you can cross apply them against the `IDOC` element (Intermediate Document) like so...

```sql
declare @xml xml =
N'<INVOIC02 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="INVOIC02.xsd">
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1" />
    <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
      <QUALF>009</QUALF>
      <BELNR>239238232</BELNR>
      <DATUM>20190111</DATUM>
    </E1EDK02>
    <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
      <QUALF>001</QUALF>
      <BELNR>592382323</BELNR>
      <DATUM>20190104</DATUM>
    </E1EDK02>
    <E1EDK02 SEGMENT="1">
      <QUALF>002</QUALF>
      <BELNR>292847342</BELNR>
      <DATUM>20190104</DATUM>
    </E1EDK02>
  </IDOC>
</INVOIC02>';

select
  InvoiceNumber.value('(QUALF/text())[1]', 'varchar(3)') as Invoice_QUALF,
  InvoiceNumber.value('(BELNR/text())[1]', 'varchar(35)') as Invoice_BELNR,
  InvoiceNumber.value('(DATUM/text())[1]', 'date') as Invoice_DATUM,
  InvoiceNumber.value('(UZEIT/text())[1]', 'time') as Invoice_UZEIT,

  CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber.value('(QUALF/text())[1]', 'varchar(3)') as PurchaseOrder_QUALF,
  CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber.value('(BELNR/text())[1]', 'varchar(35)') as PurchaseOrder_BELNR,
  CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber.value('(DATUM/text())[1]', 'date') as PurchaseOrder_DATUM,
  CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber.value('(UZEIT/text())[1]', 'time') as PurchaseOrder_UZEIT,

  SupplierOrderNumber.value('(QUALF/text())[1]', 'varchar(3)') as SupplierOrder_QUALF,
  SupplierOrderNumber.value('(BELNR/text())[1]', 'varchar(35)') as SupplierOrder_BELNR,
  SupplierOrderNumber.value('(DATUM/text())[1]', 'date') as SupplierOrder_DATUM,
  SupplierOrderNumber.value('(UZEIT/text())[1]', 'time') as SupplierOrder_UZEIT

from @xml.nodes('/INVOIC02/IDOC') as IDOC(IntermediateDocument)
cross apply IntermediateDocument.nodes('E1EDK02[QUALF/text()="009"]') E1EDK02_009(InvoiceNumber)
cross apply IntermediateDocument.nodes('E1EDK02[QUALF/text()="001"]') E1EDK02_001(CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber)
cross apply IntermediateDocument.nodes('E1EDK02[QUALF/text()="002"]') E1EDK02_002(SupplierOrderNumber);
```

| Invoice_QUALF | Invoice_BELNR | Invoice_DATUM | Invoice_UZEIT | PurchaseOrder_QUALF | PurchaseOrder_BELNR | PurchaseOrder_DATUM | PurchaseOrder_UZEIT | SupplierOrder_QUALF | SupplierOrder_BELNR | SupplierOrder_DATUM | SupplierOrder_UZEIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 009 | 239238232 | 2019-01-11 | null | 001 | 592382323 | 2019-01-04 | null | 002 | 292847342 | 2019-01-04 | null |

---

Edit: after example `ZINVOIC2` data was provided in the question...

The following query will produce the result set that you've asked for, but depending on your goals that result set may not be entirely useful since it is multiplying the iDoc Partner Profile Data against the iDoc Reference Data:

```sql
select 
  GeneralData.value('(BELNR/text())[1]', 'char(15)') as INV_NO,
  PartnerProfile.value('(PARVW/text())[1]', 'char(10)') as CUST_NO,
  PartnerProfile.value('(NAME1/text())[1]', 'char(50)') as CUST_NAME,
  ReferenceData.value('(QUALF/text())[1]', 'char(50)') as QUALF
from @XML.nodes('/ZINVOIC2/IDOC') IDOC(IntermediateDocument)
cross apply IntermediateDocument.nodes('E1EDK01') E1EDK01(GeneralData)
cross apply IntermediateDocument.nodes('E1EDKA1') E1EDKA1(PartnerProfile)
cross apply IntermediateDocument.nodes('E1EDK02') E1EDK02(ReferenceData)
order by row_number() over (order by ReferenceData, PartnerProfile);
```

| INV_NO | CUST_NO | CUST_NAME | QUALF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9650019904 | RS | XYZ Company | 009 |
| 9650019904 | AG | OILS LTD | 009 |
| 9650019904 | RE | OILS LTD | 009 |
| 9650019904 | RG | OILS LTD | 009 |
| 9650019904 | BK | XYZ Mktg Br | 009 |
| 9650019904 | RS | XYZ Company | 002 |
| 9650019904 | AG | OILS LTD | 002 |
| 9650019904 | RE | OILS LTD | 002 |
| 9650019904 | RG | OILS LTD | 002 |
| 9650019904 | BK | XYZ Mktg Br | 002 |
| 9650019904 | RS | XYZ Company | 012 |
| 9650019904 | AG | OILS LTD | 012 |
| 9650019904 | RE | OILS LTD | 012 |
| 9650019904 | RG | OILS LTD | 012 |
| 9650019904 | BK | XYZ Mktg Br | 012 |
| 9650019904 | RS | XYZ Company | 017 |
| 9650019904 | AG | OILS LTD | 017 |
| 9650019904 | RE | OILS LTD | 017 |
| 9650019904 | RG | OILS LTD | 017 |
| 9650019904 | BK | XYZ Mktg Br | 017 |
| 9650019904 | RS | XYZ Company | 087 |
| 9650019904 | AG | OILS LTD | 087 |
| 9650019904 | RE | OILS LTD | 087 |
| 9650019904 | RG | OILS LTD | 087 |
| 9650019904 | BK | XYZ Mktg Br | 087 |

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, it is a mystery to me how it is possible to answer such question without a minimal reproducible example ##1-4. It known next to anything about input XML namespaces, same with the desired output.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Unfortunately I've been exposed to numerous SAP integrations over the years.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, good deal. Please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky with pleasure! Thank you for taking the initiative.

Comment: Still does not return values for me with above query.

Comment: @avanijain Feel free to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71180057/edit) your question to include some sample data - as XML, in text format, instead of screen shots - and your expected results.

Comment: Just updated my code and xml data. What is the purpose of cross apply here?

Comment: @avanijain The cross applies as I've used them above allow you to enhance your result set with additional columns of information, so not unlike joins. Cross apply and/or outer apply make it easier to consume table-oriented functions like `nodes()`, with cross apply used where rows are expected and outer apply used where rows are optional.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for. I will filter out data based of cross apply like your first query.  Initially I had created separate queries with separate xpaths.